# Rearranging Custom-Installed Panel Indicators

Tags: indicator

I've seen a lot of other threads about people how to rearrange the panel icons, such as Networking, Time, Volume etc. However, I have installed two custom indicators, and I really would prefer to have the 2nd one in (My Workspace indicator) to be the farthest left. Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no user friendly way of doing that in upstream Unity, so I guess it's not available in the plugin you're using either.